# C++ reading in a text file with numbers

Tags: c++, io

I have a txt file with 16 lines of integers.  Each line contains 5 integers, here are the first 4 lines of the file,

> 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 5 4 3 2 1
>
> 5 100 1000 10000 10500

I need to read one line at a time, store all 5 ints in an array, then find the max value.  I can do this on my own just fine.  What I am having trouble with is going to the next line in the file after I finish reading the previous line.

1. Read first line from text file
2. store numbers in an array
3. send array to a function that returns the largest integer in the array
4. place that returned number in a new array that will eventually contain the largest numbers from all 16 lines of the file
5. read the next line of the file
6. write the array with the 16 int array to a file

I am having trouble with step 5. Each time I run my code, it reads line 1 every time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    int temp[5];
    //ask user
    cout<<"How many lines are in the file\n";
    cin>>n;
    int *array = new int[n];
    //open file
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("input.txt");

    for(j=0;j<n;++j)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        {
            inFile >> temp[i];
            cout<<temp[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I don't have the find max value function yet, I want to fix how I am reading the file before I move on to analyzing the actual data.

And yes this is a homework project, due in a few days, but my teacher did not even explain reading in files and told us to read the explanation in the textbook (which didn't help for what we were doing).  I am looking to learn not just pass the homework, so a brief explanation/example of what I'm missing is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. I believe there is a problem with opening a file, so it keeps outputting the temp[] elements as they were initialized. Try to get the inFile state while reading.

Comment: that is what I am already doing.  In my final program I won't output each number as its read, I put that in for debugging purposes.  Unless I am misunderstanding you, that is why i have     inFile >> temp[i];
    cout<<temp[i]<<" ";

Comment: Your output isn't so much illustrative for me - the initial temp[] values are similar to the contents of the first line. Try initializing temp[] as {-1}, that will actually show more:) UPD: if that modification doesn't change anything, please provide me with some information about your platform and developer ware you are using - that behavior can be interesting.

Comment: I took away the initialization of temp and added in a cout \n so it shows the output for each line on their own line in the terminal instead of all together.  the output changed, but all 16 lines show this, 0 0 1880267544 32654 1

Comment: I'd have added one more output at the very beginning just to make sure these are not the initial values of temp[]. And have a try of fscanf().

Comment: I added a cout loop right after the temp to check, and yes they are the initial values, so I guess my problem is it isn't reading in the file correctly?

Comment: Exactly. Try specifying full file name or fixing access permissions.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I put in the full file path and my original code is working :)

Answer (score 1):

I would grab the entire line at once using using [istream::getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) and then parse the resultant string.  Then call getline() again, etc.  As it is you're probably not reading in the endline character although why you're getting the exact behavior you are isn't quite clear to me.

Comment: would line 1 be istream::getline(0)? or (1) or does that function not even take a value?

Comment: @Will Check out the doc page I linked to.  The arguments are a pointer to the char array which holds input string, a max number of characters to read in, and (optionally) the delimiter you want to use.

Comment: thanks, but I am really just starting C++ (I have a decent understanding of C) and I am not sure how to parse the char string getline gives you to my numbers.

Comment: @Will Meet [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/).  This allows you to break the C string into the individual numbers (then use atoi or something to convert to integers).  The description is a little confusing but if you use the example as a template you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: Thank you for the help and I can see how that method might turn out cleaner, but do you know of any way to tell inFile from ifstream to read the next line?

Comment: @Will This is exactly the answer I gave you, call inFile.getline()

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think you need an array. Just read in line by line, tokenize it, static cast each to int (look at ascii values within the number range 0-9 for beingextra cautious, check for negatives etc.) and directly store the max. Repeat till EOF and you would possibly have the most efficient solution.

So the steps would be

1) Declare a temporary string.

2) Read in a line

3) Tokenize on the space

4) Assume the first is the max. Continue reading and comparing. Swap the values if you find a larger one

5) Repeat till the end